# Coordinator layout scroll flag to automatically show when the top is reached

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-coordinatorlayout

I have a fragment which uses a coordinator layout to show an AppBarLayout and a recycler view like this:

[image]

The layout file is thus far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        app:elevation="4dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <RelativeLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|snap">

            <!-->Content removed<-->

        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/fragment_recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

The problem I'm having is that if I fling the recycler view so that the list scrolls all the way to the top, the AppBarLayout doesn't reveal unless I specifically pull down again. Is there a scroll flag to make the AppBarLayout come down when the recycler view reaches the top, as if it's attached to the first item in the recycler view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, transferring inertial is a [known issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=179501) with nested scrolling in general, both with the platform APIs and those used by `CoordinatorLayout`.